# Inserting None values into DynamoDB using Boto

Tags: python, nosql, boto, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to Boto, and I'm trying to use it to insert a Python dictionary into Amazon DynamoDB.  I must be missing something, because the "dynamizer" (encoder) does not seem to support None values.  This is a problem because the source data has tons of nulls in it.  I could go through each row and delete out all of the key/value items where the value is None, but somehow I feel like a package as sophisticated as Boto should take care of that for me.  I'm simply trying to insert one row like so:

```
conn = DynamoDBConnection(region=RegionInfo(endpoint="dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"))
dest = Table('d_company', connection=conn)
data = {"company_id":99999, "company_name":None}
dest.put_item(data)
```

...and this gives me the error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestDynamoDB.py", line 37, in testPutIntoDynamoDB
    dest.put_item(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto\dynamodb2\table.py", line 452, in put_item
    return item.save(overwrite=overwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto\dynamodb2\items.py", line 362, in save
    final_data = self.prepare_full()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto\dynamodb2\items.py", line 265, in prepare_full
    final_data[key] = self._dynamizer.encode(value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto\dynamodb\types.py", line 228, in encode
    dynamodb_type = self._get_dynamodb_type(attr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto\dynamodb\types.py", line 220, in _get_dynamodb_type
    return get_dynamodb_type(attr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto\dynamodb\types.py", line 110, in get_dynamodb_type
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: Unsupported type "<type 'NoneType'>" for value "None"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. While [boto](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/index.html) is sophisticated indeed, you have to remember, that it does not have the knowledge of your business logic.

For example, there are at least a few ways someone can think of saving `None` to DynamoDB database:

- as "None" string
- as empty string
- don't save at all - remember, it is NoSQL database, attributes are not required

The best way to determine it - is your code. If your data could be `None`, don't add it to the dictionary.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution different from this, as I already suggested it.  But, since no one else has responded, I guess I'll mark it as the correct answer.  Thanks.

Comment: DynamoDB does not allow one to store empty strings.

Comment: Doesn't cover the case of for instance removing a ttl from a record, which is what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 14):

Attribute values in DynamoDB can be neither empty strings nor empty sets. While I discovered this empirically, the most direct reference I see to this is here:

http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/dynamodb/latest/dynamodb-dg.pdf

So the second bullet suggested by the approved answer will not work.

The third bullet of the accepted answer is the best approach, as implied by the accepted answer. From a design perspective, it more closely aligns with the NoSql paradigm and will likely provide *some* degree of efficiency over attempting to identify for each data type a None/NULL representation and storing it. This paradigm then manifests itself in your logic as checking existence/membership of the key (if/then or try/except, depending on the scenario) as opposed to checking the key for a "None/NULL equivalent" value.

If you truly seek to store attributes with a value that you equate to NULL/None, I'd recommend establishing a unique/proprietary value for accomplishing this within your application, something more identifiable than, in the case of a string, just 'None'.

(I'd rather have simply commented on the existing answer, but my status as a new user on stackoverflow evidently prevents me from doing so...hope this wasn't poor etiquette...)

Comment: It's now seven years later, and this still doesn't seem to be part of the official doc. Amazon and also the community of the awswrangler package need to address this. I was inserting hundreds of items and wondering why I don't see any in my table, until I read this post.

IMO at least the awswrangler package should give an error if ANY of the values inside an item are 'None', an empty list/set, empty string etc.

Answer (score 5):

Update - May 2020
AWS update [DynamoDB supports Null and empty objects](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/05/amazon-dynamodb-now-supports-empty-values-for-non-key-string-and-binary-attributes-in-dynamodb-tables/)

As per this update -

> Amazon DynamoDB now supports empty values for non-key String and Binary attributes in DynamoDB tables. Empty value support gives you greater flexibility to use attributes for a broader set of use cases without having to transform such attributes before sending them to DynamoDB. List, Map, and Set data types also support empty String and Binary values.

> Partition key and sort key attributes of base tables continue to require non-empty values for all data types, including String and Binary. Similarly, String and Binary key attributes of local secondary indexes or global secondary indexes also require non-empty values.

To put null attribute use type "NULL" and value as True.

**Python**:
`AttributeUpdates["MyNull"] = {'Value': {'NULL': True}, 'Action': 'PUT'}`

To put empty String attribute use type "S" and value as "".

**Python**:
`AttributeUpdates["MyEmptyString"] = {'Value': {'S': ""}, 'Action': 'PUT'}`

This will be a valid dynamoDB put_item payload.
More details - [API_PutItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html)